# macro reshape table from the wide to the long format

Tags: sas

I am a SAS newbie. I try to create a a macro that reshape a matrix to the long format.
More specifically, having a matrix i,j I want to transform it to a table :

```
 Table(col,row,value)
```

Here my code, I am using `proc transpose`:

```
%macro reshape(in_A = ,
            ou_A= );

    /* add new sequence column */
    data _&in_A.;
        set &in_A.;
        row = _n_;
    run;
    /* reshape the matrix by row to long format */
    proc transpose data=_&in_A. out=__&in_A.;
       by row;
    run;
    /* rename column and remove extra column*/
    data &ou_A.;
      set __&in_A. (rename=(col1=value));
      drop _name_;
    run; 
    /* remove temporary data sets */
    PROC DATASETS;
        DELETE permute _&in_A.;
        DELETE permute __&in_A.;
    QUIT;
%mend;
```

My code works fine but I fee that I over complicated the task? Does anyone can tell me if there is a smpler method ( in base SAS of course)? Or at least how I can simplify my macro? Easier method  to create temporary tables?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of this in a single `data step`.

```
/*make up a matrix that is 100rowsx10cols*/
data have;
array myCols{*} col1-col10;
do i = 1 to 100;
    do j = 1 to dim(myCols);
    myCols{j}=ranuni(123);
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i j;
run;
```

The above dataset will have exactly 100 rows and 10 columns not including row/column identifiers (if you are viewing the dataset inside Enterprise Guide - you will see row & column names in the margins).

```
data want;
set have;
/*loading the 10 columns into an array*/
array turnTheseColumnsAround{*} _numeric_;
i = _n_;/*specifying the row identifier*/
do j = 1 to dim(turnTheseColumnsAround);
/*going through each of the 10 elements in the array and output them to a new line*/
   value= turnTheseColumnsAround{j};
    output;
end;
keep i j value; 
run;
```

The above dataset will have exactly three columns and the no. of rows will be equal to 100x10.

A macro-version:

```
%macro reshape(in_A = ,
            ou_A= );
data &ou_A.;
set &in_A.;
array turnTheseColumnsAround{*} _numeric_;
i = _n_;
do j = 1 to dim(turnTheseColumnsAround);
   value= turnTheseColumnsAround{j};
    output;
end;
keep i j value;
run;
%mend;


%reshape(in_A=have, ou_A=want2);
```

Comment: Tanhk you +1. I see the key is to use an array! What if you put this in a macro?

Comment: @agstudy: it is simply a matter of putting the second data step inside your macro and macrotise the input & output parameters. Updated my answer.